# Xamarin forms add FLyoutPage to FavouritePageList

Tags: sqlite, listview, xamarin, favorites

I want to make a favorite page list but OnPropertyChanged(); does not work.
I add a little button to my flyoutpage item when i click on this a popup shown on the screen then i could add favorite list that selected flyoutpage but in my homepage this favorite list doesn't refresh and show new page here. [image]

This picture show my favorite page list but when i add to fav it doesn't refresh. [image]

Here is my code to fill favorite page. :

```
async void fillFavPageList()
        {
            
            FlyoutItemPage f = new FlyoutItemPage(1, "Page1", typeof(Page1));
            FlyoutItemPage f1 = new FlyoutItemPage(2, "Page2", typeof(Page2));
            FlyoutItemPage f2 = new FlyoutItemPage(3, "Page3", typeof(Page3));

            MenuListm.Add(f);
            MenuListm.Add(f1);
            MenuListm.Add(f2);
            var mlist = await App.MyDatabase.ReadPages();
         

            for (int i = 0; i < MenuListm.Count; i++)

            {
                    foreach (var item in mlist)
                    {
                        if (item.PAGEID == MenuListm[i].PageID)
                        {
                        
                        if (!MyFavPageList.Contains(MenuListm[i])) {

                            MyFavPageList.Add(MenuListm[i]);
                        }

                        }

                    }
                
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
```

Do you have any advice to make this ?

To make favorite list from flyoutpage's popup menu.

Comment: I notice that you are using the SQLite database. You can add a bool variable for the flyoutpageitem in the database and set the true or false for each flyoutpageitem by using the button add to fav you provided. Then you can use the list to get the items which the bool has been set as true.

Comment: Did you use a Community Toolkit popup? How did you get ```MyFavPageList``` from flyoutpage's popup?

Comment: FlyoutItemPage f = new FlyoutItemPage(item.PAGEID, item.Name, typeof(DepoAktarımPage), "@drawable/transport.png", item.GRUP, item.PROGRAMKOD);
                    MyFavPageList.Add(f); 
 That is how I fill MyFavPageList. I have used Rg.Plugn.PopUpPage.

Comment: Did you create a new instance of MyFavPageList on pop up page?

Comment: Because I assume that you define a  ObservableCollection MyFavPageList in the viewModel of Favourite list page. So I wonder how you get this viewModel instance on popup page. Was this viewModel a singleton?

Comment: FlyoutItemPage contains type of content page information. I save this FlyoutItemPage to sqlite. It's not a singleton. It works very well now. Do I need to use singleton here ? If you want I can share Favorite page viewmodel.

Comment: Of course, you can share your code here. I haven't come up with a good idea except using a singleton, so I ask you in that way. That doesn't mean you have to use a singleton.

Comment: https://www.paste.tc/profilepageviewmodel That is my viewmodel. It's mixed Turkish and English but I think you can understand.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, and glad it works very well now!